# Object A has a List of Object B, Proper Way for Object B to Alter Class A?

Tags: c#, oop, game-engine

I've done my best to research this issue on my own, but I've been unable to find a good answer. Most likely because I don't know the proper way to ask the question. So I'm just going to throw everything out there.

This is the basic structure of the two classes I have. (Obviously not actual code.)

```
class ship
{
    public int baseStat = 0;    //I want this to be protected
    public int derivedStat = 0; //This should also be protected
    public int DerivedStat{ get { return derivedStat ; } }

    private List<Component> components;

    public void DeriveStats()
    {
        foreach(Component component in components)
        {
            component.DeriveStats(this);
        }
    }
}

class Component
{
    public void DeriveStats(Ship ship)
    {
        ship.derivedStat = ship.baseStat + 5;
    }
}
```

This all works just fine, I have many different types of Component subclasses that do different things to the ship and it's stats, but with this setup, all stats are viewable and modifiable outside the ship class. Design wise, this doesn't seem correct, and frankly, it's driving me bonkers.

Is there a cleaner/more correct way I can approach this?

EDIT-

Big thank you to everyone who commented and gave an answer, it was a huge help. In case anyone else stumbles upon this question, here's how I went about addressing the issue.

```
abstract class Ship
{
    //Locking variable that only allows the ship's stats to be updated when true
    private bool _isModifying = false;

    //General Stats that define a ship******************************

    //Layers of shields
    protected int baseShields;
    public int DerivedShields
    {
        get{ return DerivedShields; }
        set
        {
            if (_isModifying)
                DerivedShields = value;
            else
                throw (new Exception("Ship stats cannot be modified outside the ship class."));
        }
    }

    //**************************************************************

    protected List<Component> installedComponents;

    public void DeriveStats()
    {
        _isModifying = true;

        foreach (Component component in installedComponents)
        {
            component.DeriveStats(this);
        }

        _isModifying = false;
    }
}

class BasicShield : Component
{
    public override void DeriveStats(Ship ship)
    {
        ship.DerivedShields = ship.DerivedShields + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: are the components parts of the ship?

Comment: you probably want to have a method in ship that calculates stats on the fly

Comment: Make the public fields private and create public methods to get and set these fields. Or use properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add methods to `Ship` that will allow others to alter `Ship` but gives `Ship` the responsibility for and ability to ensure its own consistency. This means that

1. external parties can request that `Ship` be updated, but `Ship` can deny such requests if they would violate some constraint (or if `Ship` just doesn't feel like being updated for whatever reason).
2. you can give these methods names that convey the semantics of the operation, while you decouple the implementation details of `Ship` from the rest of your program. You gain the freedom to change the way you represent a `Ship`s internal state.

**EDIT:**

If you want each Component to implement the algorithm that determines the new stats, you could

1. Make the ship's properties be read-only (they will have to be visible for the component to make its calculations)
2. Make the component's DeriveStats(...) method return the calculated value
3. Make the ship itself call DeriveStats(...) and update its values accordingly.

This has the added benefit that the ship is in charge of aggregating results from different components. As the components don't know about each other, how would they ever coordinate who gets to decide the ship's stats?

Comment: Yes, that is the general idea I have for it. You would add components to the ship, and the ship would handle determining it's stats when you call Ship.DeriveStats. Unfortunately, I would like to make baseStat and derivedStat both 'protected' variables but I can't with my current setup.

How can I allow the component class to alter this ship without making the stats variables public?

Comment: Thank you, this is a very helpful answer. The reason I have the component class handling updates is that there are many different types of components, that will be altering the ship in different ways. So when the Ship class calls DeriveStats for each component, it doesn't actually know which stat that particular component is going to be interested in modifying.

Comment: Then how do you avoid conflicts between components - won't they be overwriting each other's values? How do you ensure that the ship's stats are consistent (say, within certain ranges or whatever)? You may have valid reasons, but to me it seems very brittle.

Comment: Well, generally each component's effect is additive. So if say, the ship has a shield component, it will look at the current derivedShieldStat and add 1 to it and be done. Any other components can come along and do the same. I realize now that the relationship between baseStat and derivedStat wasn't very clear. baseStat is only used in resetting all the values of a ship prior to looping through the component list and doing updates. Again, thank you, I think this should be enough info to get me headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways

The component should calculate stuff (stats in yr case) and return it. The the ship class updates itself with the returned value

```
    ...
    public void DeriveStats()
    {
        foreach(Component component in components)
        {
            derivedStat = component.DeriveStats(this);

        }
    }


class Component
{
    public int DeriveStats(Ship ship)
    {
        return ship.baseStat + 5;
    }
}
```

The ship has an UpdateStats method that the components call.

```
    ...
    public void DeriveStats()
    {
        foreach(Component component in components)
        {
            component.DeriveStats(this);
        }
    }
}

class Component
{
    public void DeriveStats(Ship ship)
    {
        ship.UpdateStats(ship.baseStat + 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use properties to keep the same base stat, and calculate the ship's effective stat based off it's components.

```
class Ship
{
    private int _baseStat = 0;    //I want this to be protected
    public int CalculatedStat
    {   
        get
        {
            int result = _baseStat;        
            foreach(Component component in components)
            {
                result += component.Modifier 
                // you'll have to add modifier to Component yourself
                // in this case, you'd set it to 5
            }   
            return result;
        }
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can declare your properties like this so they are protected.

```
public int BaseStat ( get; protected set; }
public int DerivedStat { get; protected set; }
```

Secondly, based on the scenario described, the following might be a better property for you.  Or, if you don't want it continuously calculated you can update the protected property from 'Ship' in a similar manner.

```
public int DerivedStat
{
    get
    {
        var derivedStat = 0;
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            derivedStat += baseStat + 5;
        }

        return derivedStat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are nearly there with `public int DerivedStat{ get { return derivedStat ; } }` - using accessors for your should-be-protected fields. In this very basic example, you can do some validation in the set method, as shown below. That way, other classes won't see the internal structure of your `ship`, but they can *attempt* to modify it.

What about the following:

```
class ship
{
    protected int baseStat = 0;    //I want this to be protected - now it is
    private int derivedStat = 0; //This should also be protected - can even be private
    public int DerivedStat {
        get 
        {
            return derivedStat;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value < 0)
                throw new Exception("Validate your data here!");
            derivedStat = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me very close. The only class that should be modifying the Ship's stats is the Component class. Would there be any way for me to check for that in the 'set' method?

If not, I think the data validation on set should be sufficient to protect the Ship class. ;]

Comment: No, there is no good, simple way to find out whether something else than a `Component` is trying to modify it. You might be able to control it by reading the stack trace (see if a given line of it contains the expected namespace/class name), but it's not a very clean thing to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Via event on B handled by A...

A can register to B's events on addition of an A to its collection and unregister upon removal by using an ObservableCollection and monitoring its changes.